# How do I retrieve all the orders from my product schema using response.send

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my Product schema

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Course is required"]
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Description is required"]
    },
    price : {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "Price is required"]
    },
    stocks: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "Stocks is required"]
    },
    isActive:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    createdOn : {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date()
    },
    orders : [
        {
            userId: {
                type: String,
                required: [true, "UserId is required"]
            },
            userEmail: {
                type: String,
                required: [true, "UserEmail is required"]
            },
            quantity: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0
            },
            purchasedOn: {
                type: Date,
                default: new Date()
            }
        }       
    ]
});
// This is my controller

module.exports.getAllOrders = async (request, response) => {
    const hassedPassword = await auth.decode(request.headers.authorization);
    if(hassedPassword.isAdmin){
        await Products.find({})
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            response.send(result.orders); // This part will show null
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            response.send(error);
        });
    }
    else {
        return response.status(401).send("User must be ADMIN to access this functionality");
    }
}
```

Tried result.orders but getting a null value. I'm still a newbie and trying my best to understand this code. I did some research but still not getting any answer to this. If I will use `.findById()` and then use a response of `result.orders`, this will work. But for multiple orders using `.find()`, I'm not getting any result at all.

Answer (score 1):

`result` is an array, try to `map` on it:

```
module.exports.getAllOrders = async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const hassedPassword = await auth.decode(request.headers.authorization);
    if (hassedPassword.isAdmin) {
      const products = await Products.find({}).lean();
      const orders = products.map((p) => p.orders).flat();
      response.send(orders);
    } else {
      return response
        .status(401)
        .send('User must be ADMIN to access this functionality');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    response.send(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this. I tried using .map, but couldn't understand it properly.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me. I'm currently studying your code.